# nth problems or unwanted behavior

Tags: string, rust, iterator

Hy, I have been testing the iterators behavior to understand when the iterators get updated. Then I stumbled upon on following behavior.

The string TutorialsPoint is being iterated over, by mixed functions nth and next. Now next always shows the next item in the string, basically the index 0, but the nth(0) does not give me the letter at index 0 but index 1. Am I missing something here? Is this normal and wanted behavior?

The same behavior is there for chars and char_indices.

```
let company:&str="TutorialsPoint";
let mut test_tuple = company.char_indices();
println!("Char indices test next: {:?}",  test_tuple);
test_tuple.next();
println!("Char indices test next: {:?}",  test_tuple);
test_tuple.nth(1);
println!("Char indices test next: {:?}",  test_tuple);
test_tuple.next_back();
println!("Char indices test next: {:?}",  test_tuple);
```

Output:

```
Char indices test next: CharIndices { front_offset: 0, iter: Chars(['T', 'u', 't', 'o', 'r', 'i', 'a', 'l', 's', 'P', 'o', 'i', 'n', 't']) }
Char indices test next: CharIndices { front_offset: 1, iter: Chars(['u', 't', 'o', 'r', 'i', 'a', 'l', 's', 'P', 'o', 'i', 'n', 't']) }
Char indices test next: CharIndices { front_offset: 3, iter: Chars(['o', 'r', 'i', 'a', 'l', 's', 'P', 'o', 'i', 'n', 't']) }
Char indices test next: CharIndices { front_offset: 3, iter: Chars(['o', 'r', 'i', 'a', 'l', 's', 'P', 'o', 'i', 'n']) }
```

Is there any papers or guidance how this is concepted? I would like to know serious things like these in advance if possible.

The nth function after the next should begin at the "t" letter not "o". As the title says the problem is the nth function not the next, depends how one sees it. And the next problem is why is nth 0 not pointing to  the first element in the string means the same as next?

Comment: This is expected behavior -- each call to `next` "advances" the iterator ahead by an element. See the [Rust book's chapter on iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html) and the [`std::iter` module documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html) for more details.

Comment: The nth after the next should begin at the "t" letter not "o". As the title says the problem is the nth function not the next, depends how one sees it. And the next problem is why is nth 0 not pointing to  the first element in the string means the same as next?

Comment: The call to `next` returns `"T"` and advances the pointer to the `"u"`. Then the call to `nth(1)` discards the `"u"` (item 0 of the remaining items), returns the `"t"` (item 1) and advances the pointer to the `"o"`.

Comment: @MarkoBencik The `nth` function returns the `n`th element from the _start_ of the iterator. Also, iterators are not reversible -- once you advance it with `next`, you cannot "rewind" back to the previous element. As such, the `nth` function has nothing do with indexing in the traditional sense, as iterators are _not_ collections and (typically) do not store the elements they yield. It looks like you may not have fully understood how iterators work; I would recommend (re) reading the Rust book, iterator documentation, and look up tutorials if necessary.

Comment: @EvilTak should be noted that `nth` returns the nth element from the start of *the `nth` iterator* (the adapted iterator), not whatever the original iterator might be. The confusion actually makes sense if you assume that `nth` works on any ancestor other than the direct parent in the state it was at call time: `nth(1)` does not return the second item of `company.char_indices()`, but of whatever `test_tuple` was when it was called.

Comment: @MarkoBencik it might be clearer if you interpret `nth(n)` not as an indexing operation but as `.skip(n-1).next()`, as that is in effect what it does (though in practice the implementation is the other way around, `skip` calls `nth`) to advance the iterator, discarding its result).

Comment: @Masklinn thanks for that clarification -- I assumed that was obvious, but I can now see how it may not be.

Comment: @Masklinn thanks for the clarification, how it works I took a look in the source code, and was scratching my head, why would one do this. My initial thinking was that out of C++ but I was proven wrong. The guys from Rust should revise the documentation, just to avoid any confusion for people that come with other backgrounds.