# Disparity in accessing command-line arguments using nth()

Tags: rust, command-line-arguments

I am trying to access command-line parameters using nth() and unwrap(). using two different approaches. *One using a **function** to get the arg at the nth position*,  and the other *initializing variables with argument values*.

```
use std::env::{args, Args};
fn main() {
    // Approach 1 (using the function) [WORKS]:
    println!("{} {} {}",
      get_nth_arg(1),
      get_nth_arg(2),
      get_nth_arg(3)
    );

    // Approach 2 (DOES NOT WORK (Panics)):
    // Works if run with ..nth(1), ..nth(0), ..nth(0)
    let mut args: Args = args();
    let arg1: String = args.nth(1).unwrap();
    let arg2: String = args.nth(2).unwrap();
    let arg3: String = args.nth(3).unwrap();
    println!("{} {} {}", arg1, arg2, arg3);
}

fn get_nth_arg(n: usize) -> String {
    args().nth(n).unwrap()
}
```

***Approach 1*** has no issues and seems to work logically.

***Approach 2*** seems to work with the parameters to **nth()** given as 1,0,0 in order; but panics when 1,2 and 3 are given as parameters.

Why does **nth()** need different sets of parameters to work for these two approaches?

Comment: `.nth()` takes the nth *remaining* item. `.next()` is the same as `.nth(0)`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Duplicate of [nth problems or unwanted behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70505627/nth-problems-or-unwanted-behavior).

Comment: @Coder-256 I'm not using .next() in this code

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I read that question; and understood that the iterator is advanced with each call. If that's the case, then shouldn't nth() called with [1,0,0] work for Approach 1? In other words, why isn't the iterator being advanced when using Approach 1?

Comment: @AlbinKC In approach 11, you re-generate the `args()` on each time. Each call you generate a distinct iterator, you can advance separately from the other instances.

Answer (score 1):

`.nth()` mutates the iterator it's called on. In approach 1, this isn't a problem since a new `Args` iterator is created in each call to `get_nth_arg`. But in approach 2, the same iterator is used for each `.nth()` call. Here's what happens:

```rust
let mut args: Args = args();
// At position 0, nothing has been taken from the iterator
let arg1: String = args.nth(1).unwrap(); // take 1 item from the iterator
// At position 1
let arg2: String = args.nth(2).unwrap(); // take 2 items from the *existing* iterator
// At position 3
let arg3: String = args.nth(3).unwrap(); // take 3 items from the *existing* iterator
// At position 6
println!("{} {} {}", arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Another way to look at this is to replace the `nth` calls with the equivalent calls to `.next()`:

```rust
let mut args: Args = args();
let arg1: String = args.next().unwrap();
let _ = args.next().unwrap(); // discard 1 element for nth(2)
let arg2: String = args.next().unwrap();
let _ = args.next().unwrap(); // discard 2 elements for nth(3)
let _ = args.next().unwrap();
let arg3: String = args.next().unwrap();
println!("{} {} {}", arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Remember, iterator don't remember past elements. Once you call `next` on an iterator, you can't "go back" to get a previous element. You can *only* get new elements from an iterator.